# I wanted to bind multiple dataframe using rbind

Tags: r

I wanted to bind five dataframe df1, df2, df3, df4, and df5. However, using fast.rbind() is returning error saying

> fast.rbind() is not found.

Comment: Where do you expect do find `fast.rbind`?

Comment: Use `library(dplyr) bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)`

Comment: problem is df2 would have extra columns. above is returning columns is not matching. I used fast.rbind(df1,df2, df3, df4, df5, method = "common")

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following -

```
#get the 5 dataframes in a list
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:5))
#Get the common column names
common_cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, colnames))
#select only the common columns from each dataframe and bind it to one dataframe.
result <- purrr::map_df(list_df, `[`, common_cols)
```

Or the last step can be changed to

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list_df, `[`, common_cols))
```

to keep everything in base R.